# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in Postman

Tags: express, testing, routes, postman, backend

I just tried to test the server with Postman and the above error occurred. *Get* request is properly worked but *Post* request is not working properly. My `server.js` file code is shown below.

Vs code server.js file:
[image: Vs code server.js file]

Vs Code Terminal:
[image: Vs Code Terminal]

Postman Post Request:
[image: Postman Post Request]

Postman body after sending the Post Request
[image: Postman body after sending the Post Request]

Comment: In server.js post endpoint you should return `req.body.name` instead `res.body.name`,  `res.send(... ${req.body.name})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `express.json()` instead of `bodyParser.json()`